# How to create an exceptional behaviour of a UniqueEntity constraint

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, constraints

I have a tricky question of validation with my Symfony project.

I have a **User entity** with a UniqueEntity constraint on the email.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("email", message="Cet email existe déjà sur Le Parcours.")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{

    /**
     * Many users may be in one contract
     * @AppAssert\ContractUpdateNotValid(groups={"edit_user", "company_edit_user"})
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contract", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_contract", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $contract;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email(message = "L'email '{{ value }}' n'est pas valide.")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "L'email ne doit pas être vide")
     * @AppAssert\EmailTesterNotExists(groups={"new_tester"})
     */
    private $email;
    
    [...]
```

And a **Contract entity** with a OneToMany relation with the User entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="contracts")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="reference", message="Cette référence de session existe déjà.")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Repository\ContractRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Contract
{
    
    /**
     * One contract may have many users
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="contract", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $users;

    [...]
```

I also have a ContractType form to create a new contract. That form allows to persist new users, that's why I added `Assert\Valid` on `users` in Contract entity.

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use UserBundle\Entity\User;

class ContractType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $current_user = $options['current_user'];

        $builder
            ->add('company', EntityType::class, [
                'class'         => 'UserBundle:Company',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple'     => false,
                'expanded'     => false,
                'required'     => true,
                'empty_data'   => '',
                'placeholder'  => 'Sélectionner une entreprise',
                'label'        => 'Entreprise',
                'attr'         => ['class' => 'col-md-6'],
            ])
            ->add('seller', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Clémence' => 'clemence',
                    'Morgane'  => 'morgane',
                    'Marion'   => 'marion',
                    'Maxime'   => 'maxime',
                    'Thomas'   => 'thomas',
                ],
                'label'    => 'Commercial',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('animator', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Frédérique' => 'frederique',
                ],
                'label'    => 'Animateur',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('reference', TextType::class, [
                'label'    => 'Référence de la session',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Slots'    => 'slots',
                    'Licences' => 'licences',
                ],
                'label'    => 'Type de session',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('subscription', IntegerType::class, [
                'label'    => 'Forfait',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('duration', IntegerType::class, [
                'label'    => 'Durée de la session (en mois)',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('start', DateTimeType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'label'  => 'Débute le',
                'attr'   => [
                    'class' => 'datepicker',
                ],
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('comment', TextareaType::class, [
                'label'    => 'Commentaires des admins',
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('users', CollectionType::class, [
                'label'          => false,
                'entry_type'     => ContractUserType::class,
                'entry_options'  => ['label' => false, 'current_user' => $current_user],
                'required'       => false,
                'allow_add'      => true,
                'allow_delete'   => false,
                'by_reference'   => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ])
            ->add('managers', EntityType::class, [
                'class'         => 'UserBundle:User',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
                        ->leftJoin('m.company', 'c')
                        ->addSelect('c')
                        ->where('m.role = -1')
                        ->orWhere('m.role = 2')
                        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
                        ->addOrderBy('m.surname', 'ASC');
                },
                'group_by' => function (User $manager) {
                    return ucwords($manager->getCompany()->getName());
                },
                'choice_label' => function ($user) {
                    if ($user->getExpiration()->format('YmdHis') > date('YmdHis')) {
                        return ucwords($user->getName()).' '.ucwords($user->getSurname());
                    } else {
                        return ucwords($user->getName()).' '.ucwords($user->getSurname()).' (expiré)';
                    }
                },
                'mapped'   => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label'    => 'Attribuer un/des manager/s',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'        => 'UserBundle\Entity\Contract',
            'current_user'      => null,
            'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'new_contract'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'userbundle_contract';
    }
}
```

This form is working. It returns an error if the email of a new user added already exists.

Well, now here is my question.

I have some users that are already in my database because they just tested the application before buying it. And I would like to recognise them after having submitted the form in order to only change their data automatically, so that the commercials won't have to check before every new contract if the users in the contracts were already testers. I want the application to do it for them.

What would be the best practice to do it ?

Thanks for your help :-*

Comment: If i have understood you correctly, you want to validate the `Contract::$users` after the `ContractType` has been submitted and detect duplicate emails of testers... Than you would use a [Custom Value Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/validation/custom_constraint.html). The custom validator then has to be used instead of `@Assert\Valid()`. Whenever you check an Entity for valid data, some form of validator should be used...

Comment: Best practice is to use CQRS. :) You send message to handler, which applies your custom business logic and create new user or return existing, and then you use this user with creating contract. But it's too enterprise way.
What you really need is custom validator, which detect two things: is user exist and is user is tester. And if user exist and not tester - you create violation like UniqueEntity validator. And if user is tester - you need to _replace_ your unsaved user inside Contract with existing one, and possibly update his data. All this can be performed inside this custom validator.

Comment: So I have no choice than to recreate all my default user validations in a custom validator... I must remove the Assert\Valid. Ok then let’s do it ! But I will check CQRS to know more about it. Thank you very much :)